This module cannot be imported in server runtime. [importing @nuxt/kit from ../server/routes/request.get.ts]
After updating Nuxt "^3.7.4" to "^3.12.2" I keep getting the following error from multiple modules:
This module cannot be imported in server runtime. [importing @nuxt/kit from ../../packages/bloomreach/src/runtime/server/routes/br-request.get.ts] 
We use it in combination with Turbo which should not cause any issue as I am currently aware.
Is this a known issue? We have a fairly standard nuxt.config. This is my nuxtconfig at the moment:
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    head: {
      script: [
        {
          src: '/assets/js/lightning.js',
          tagPosition: 'bodyClose',
        },
      ],
    },
  },

  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  css: ['@pl-web/cms-ui/src/runtime/assets/styles/global.scss'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['vuetify'],
  },
  modules: [
    (_options, nuxt) => {
      nuxt.hooks.hook('vite:extendConfig', (config) => {
        // @ts-expect-error
        config.plugins.push(vuetify({ autoImport: true }))
      })
    },
    '@pinia/nuxt',
    '@nuxt/devtools',
  ],

  vite: {
    vue: {
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls,
      },
    },
  },
})


Do you maybe have @nuxt/kit as a dependency rather than a devDependency?

Doesn't seem to make a difference when i move it...

Got a Github repo?
